# How can i access shadow dom elements on a web page from a chrome extension and also a firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, shadow-dom

For example if the code on the webpage that the chrome extension is running on  has the following code, where  is part of a shadow dom. How would i target shadowtag from the extension to examine its text content?

```
<parentTag>
  #shadow-root (closed)
  <shadowTag id="textid">Text</shadowTag>
</parentTag>
```

I understand there are a couple of functions available,
chrome.dom.openOrClosedShadowRoot in the chrome extension api
and element.openOrClosedShadowRoot in firefox but I cannot find any examples of their usage, so a bit stuck as to how to use those functions to access shadow elements. Any help with this would be fantastic! :)

Comment: Not, that is the whole essence of a ``closed`` shadowRoot. The Component Developer has closed the door.

Comment: i see someone has closed this question, but i have lookd at the so called "duplicate" question, and it doesnt actually answer my question. im looking for example code that can select an element, the code listed in the answer you have linked to, does not show a specific example of the code selecting an element, which is what i am looking to do

Comment: if you check the answer that is linked to at the top (claiming its a duplicate) well it is a similar question, it has a partial explanation, of how to do it, but it doesnt answer my question, of requiring some example code. so it definitely is possible. btw i was aiming my comment at the person who closed my question not you.

Comment: sorry but you are wrong. that function returns the shadow dom root, that can be queried just like a normal dom node tree.

Comment: Yes, but its not part of the standard, only supported in FireFox, because they sneaked their own code in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/openOrClosedShadowRoot

Comment: not only supported by firefox, you really do seem to be allergic to reading and learning.